# How is this question duplicate?

Tags: support

This (now deleted) question; [Why are most of companions of The Doctor humans?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/52126/why-are-most-of-companions-of-the-doctor-humans) has been closed as duplicate of this question: 
[Does The Doctor ever have a non-British companion or non-humanoid friend?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/51380/does-the-doctor-ever-have-a-non-british-companion-or-non-humanoid-friend)

By common sense, how can they be same? That question is Yes/No type question, mine is not.

Comment: [This conversation has been had in the past](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/3194/13941), and if it needs re-visiting then some historical context should be provided.

Answer (score -1):

While your question *is* different than the other one asked, there are two answers to it that address your question.

- [JoshBirk's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/51390/5184) addresses the in-universe reason (though, arguably not in enough depth).
- [Keshlam's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/51397/5184) addresses the out-of-universe reason.

Comment: No, these answers aren't the answer to my question by any way.

Comment: Then add a comment explaining why you think so. JoshBirk's answer talks about a preference for humans who have somehow wandered into space. It's arguably not enough detail, but that's probably (I didn't VTC) where one could argue the duplicate. Keshlam's answer discusses that it's due to budget/logistic issues. Both explain, at least in part,  why they're usually humans.

Comment: @phantom42: How is a comment on a deleted question supposed to help with anything?

Comment: @Kevin It was not deleted at the time this question or answer were created. There was a month that he could participate in a discussion to explain why his question was unique or otherwise unanswered.